# How to iterate over LoadingCache google class

Tags: java, list, generics, iterator

I have a loadingcache class like this:

```
LoadingCache<Integer, List<Parent>> parents
```

Where `Parent` is a class that has `id`, `description`, `home`, and `nickname`

I want to print all the values inside that `parents` object

I tried to do something like:

```
parents.keys()
```

but I couldn't find that method for `LoodingCache` object

Answer (score 3):

You can use method `asMap()` instead:

```
  /**
   * Returns a view of the entries stored in this cache as a thread-safe map. Modifications made to
   * the map directly affect the cache.
   */
  ConcurrentMap<K, V> asMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?:

```
Set<Integer> s = parents.asMap().keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> it = s.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            int n = it.next();
            try {
                List<Parent> list = parents.get(n);
                for (Parent l : list) {
                    System.out.println(String.format(
                            "id = %s, description = %s, home = %s",
                            l.getId(), l.getDescription(), l.getHome())); // you can do more than printing to standard output 
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e); // you can do whatever you want
            }
        }
```

The LoadingCache has a method called [asMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#asMap())

The [get](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get(K)) method throws three exceptions, which are:
[ExecutionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html?is-external=true)
[UncheckedExecutionException](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/UncheckedExecutionException.html)
and [ExecutionError](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ExecutionError.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print all the `Parent` objects, this is really simple.

```
for (List<Parent> parentsGroup : parents.asMap().values()) {
  for (Parent parent : parentsGroup) {
    System.out.println(parent); // or whatever
  }
}
```